# How to fix this problem I’ve been working on

Tags: java

I’m learning how to code currently on my own before I take a couple classes. Why won’t the code below work:

```java
Point point1 = new Point (x: 1, y: 1);
```

I get an error when I try to run it in this specific section using IntelliJ.

I just need help with that part. I'm trying to learn the basics.

Comment: You say "I get an error"... it's much better if you tell US what that error is.

Comment: Java doesn't have named parameters like that, maybe you have been misguided by the parameter inlay hints which IntelliJ shows.

Answer (score 3):

What error do you get? What is the programm code for the Point constructor you are calling? What is the Java version you are targeting?

Aside from those obvious questions, one thing jumps out to me immediately:

I do not think that java has named arguments.
Try this instead:

```java
Point point1 = new Point (1, 1);
```

Comment: Jdk version 20. And thank you this helped.

Comment: If this helped, why is the other awnser marked as the solution?